# Pass an Action with string parameter into method without it

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

I want to pass an action into a method and invoke it there with parameter filePath that i get there.
If i do it like below the method gets invoked with the parameter i passed in the parameters of ExportExecute and not with filePath

```
ExportExecute(m => this.Method(null), "example")
```

leads to

```
action.Invoke(null);
```

but what i want is

```
action.Invoke(filePath);
```

My code:

```
 private void ExportExecute(Action<string> action, string fileName)
        {
            var filePath = this.ExportDialog(fileName);

        try
        {
            action.Invoke(filePath);
...
```

This does not work, the action is invoked with null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `this.Method(null)`, the param provided to `MyMethod` is `null`. But what you actually want is to provide the value of `x`:

```
this.ExportExecute(x => this.MyMethod(x), "Example")
```

or even simpler:

```
this.ExportExecute(this.MyMethod, "Example")
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved my problem by correct syntax...

The Call:

`this.ExportExecute(this.MyMethod, "Example")`

Comment: This changes literally nothing about the code.  This will behave *exactly* the same as the code in the question, other than the delegate having a different name.